# Querying a cell in a table in Dart

Tags: dom, dart, html-table, row, cell

I would like to query a particular cell of a table in order to change its text or inner HTML.

A sample of the table:

```
<table id="infotable">
  <thead></thead>
    <tbody id="tData">
      <tr>
        <td>SomeCompany1</td>
        <td>SomeProduct1</td>
        <td>PriceType1</td>
        <td id="164">Awaiting data...</td>
      </tr>
[...]
```

The third cell of the first row of the above table is my target which I have identified with the attribute `id="164"`.

In the Dart script, I have attempted two means of querying this cell:

```
TableCellElement cell = document.query('#164');
```

and

```
var cell = query('#164');
```

Both result in the following error in the Dart editor:

```
'Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this written out when I came across the answer in another SO post, but in the context of jQuery. It turns out the problem was that the id attribute was not allowed to begin with a digit.

Prepending a character to the beginning of the attribute value solved this issue (e.g. the `q` in `id="q164`".